# Undefined variable: product_status (View:

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to show that if product is in stock then it show in stock otherwise out ofstock but it says error:

controller:

```
   public function productdetail(Request $request, Product $product)
   {
    $product_status = Product::where('product_status',$product)->sum('product_status');
    return view('product.detail', compact('product'));
   }
```

blade file:

```
  <span class="s-text8 m-r-35">@if($product_status == 1) In Stock @else Out Of Stock @endif</span>
```

Comment: Use `compact('product_status')` instead of `compact('product')`

Comment: You are using wrong `var`. Use like this: `return view('product.detail', compact('product_status'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending the `product_status` variable to the view. Use like

```
return view('product.detail', compact('product','product_status'));
```

*Does your `product_status` variable has any value? I have doubt in that. Try `dd` to check if it holds anything.*

Comment: hi error removed, product_status is name of db column and all of its values are 1 but it is showing out of stock   can u plz tell me that I wants to show in stock if value is 1 in db and if value is 0 then out of stock

Comment: then you need not to do anything in your controller. in view use just use `@if($product->product_status == 1) In Stock @else Out Of Stock @endif`

Answer (score 0):

Q)   product_status is name of db column and all of its values are 1 but it is showing out of stock can u plz tell me that I wants to show in stock if value is 1 in db and if value is 0 then out of stock

Ans)   Here you should check condition for greater than equal to 1
You are checking only for ==1 so if sum is greater than 1 then also it will go to else part....

```
 @if($product->product_status >=1) 
    {{" in stock"}}
@else
 {{"Out Of Stock"}}
 @endif
```